# Precisando de tradução nas opções de sinalização

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Na descrição de alguns itens do botão <kbd>Sinalizar</kbd> estão em inglês. Segue a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só para constar, isso pode ser editado por qualquer um, basta criar uma conta no transifex e solicitar acesso ao projeto. Por exemplo a string em inglês do primeiro item pode ser encontrada aqui: https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt_BR/english/61992665?q=exists%20only

Comment: É legal que tenha a tradução colaborativa e tal, mas <opinião extremamente pessoal> a gente já colabora bastante editando, respondendo, dando suporte... o mínimo que espero da empresa é que tenham um plantel de tradutores na folha de pagamentos... </opinião xtreme>

Comment: Mesmo bug report no Metão: [On non-English sites, Flagging dialogs use a mix of English and the native language](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267732/185667)

Comment: @brasofilo engraçado que no começo eu via bastante gente revoltada com a decisão da SE de contratar uma empresa para a tradução e queria esse poder para nós, será que agora que vimos que é trabalho para caramba nossa ideia vai mudar? rs.. Um dos posts que eu achei que fala exatamente sobre isso, e tem bastante votos a favor: [Sobre partes do site em inglês](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87/3117)

Comment: Relacionado: [Mil tradutores são melhores que um](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2705/3117)

Comment: @Math, eu estou participando do Area51 pro SO em espanhol... o CM lá convocou os interessados a contribuir nas traduções... pô, preguiça danada... isto aqui já me tira um monte de tempo das atividades normais (sem reclamação, é minha escolha) mas já depender da gente pra isso também funcionar, preguiça... acho que é legal que exista essa opção  pra consertar coisas pequenas e fáceis, mas tem uma empresa que é dona disto, não é um projeto open source tipo o WordPress onde aparece lá meu nome como participante como tradutor ou reportando bugs intrínsecos do sistema cujo código eu tenho acesso

Comment: @brasofilo entendi seu ponto. De qualquer forma meu primeiro comentário foi só para mostrar a possibilidade de qualquer pessoa poder editar isso, a contribuição da tradução assim como qualquer outra participação no site é voluntária, mas acredito que muita gente desconheça essa ferramenta, por isso acreditei que valia o aviso. Se a coisa começar a ficar empacada, ou seja, muito trabalho de tradução pendente, pode ser necessário ter que rever o processo.

Comment: @Math, certamente, meu problema é com textos muito grandes, acho que meu comentário é mais um desabafo que talvez seja exagerado em relação ao que está sendo discutido aqui

Comment: O problema que não foi resolvido pela tradução colaborativa é que os caras mudam a versão em inglês, e nossas traduções já existentes deixam de valer. Justamente o tipo de problema que eu discuto [numa pergunta minha](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/64589).